# Return value checking enforcement

Tags: c++, g++, clang, return-value

If a function returns a value indicating success or failure, is there a way to ensure that all callers use or check this value?

I'm looking for something like a compiler warning or a function annotation that can be added to my c++ code, compiled with clang or GCC.